# Debugging JavaFx project with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, javafx

I'm running Eclipse Kepler, JRE 1.7, with the e(fx)clipse plugin. Whenever I try to debug a JavaFx project, I receive the "source not found" stating the systemproperties class belong to the JavaFX sdk and doesn't allow modifications. I have tried to add this class to the step filter in eclipse with no luck. I have been unable I can find source code for JavaFX from Oracle. Is there any way to get past this and debug JavaFX in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's never been a source zip of JavaFX2.2 released by Oracle because it was opensourced only partially.

I'd advice to use JDK8 which comes with the source code.

Comment: tom, on your website e(fx)eclipse, a few years ago someone named Bill had an issue with the systemproperties.setVersion(). How did you end up resolving that error?[link]http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/12/12/efxclipse-0-0-9-released/